# Why can't my powershell get any output in the console but it is OK in the CLI mode of powershell?

Tags: powershell, windows-7

I have written a power shell script to get the PATH value from regedit. (The reason I have to read it from regedit is that myscript will detect the PATH value every time after it installs something, the environment PATH value won't be reloaded until it restarts, so I need to get the value from regedit, parse it and do some operation).

This is the original script,

```
function getEnv($type){
    $retval = (Get-ItemProperty -Path "Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment" -Name $type -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
    if (($retval -eq $null) -or ($retval.Length -eq 0))
    {
        return ""
    }
    else
    {
        return $retval.$type
    }
}

getEnv   $args[0]
```

The issue is that I got nothing in the console, even if I added some "Write-host" message to the script, looks like the whole script is not loaded, but it works fine if I call the script in the powershell interactive console.

Ansgar Wiechers has given some advice, thanks very much for your help, but it still doesn't output anything. [image: This is the result]
[image: I run the script as admin, but still nothing]
[image: follow Mathias's advice, still not work]

Ansgar Wiechers & Mathias, thanks a lot for your help, I still could not get it work. I doubt it is caused by other setting, but I haven't got a thread for it.

Comment: `powershell.exe .\test.ps1 PATH -noexit`?

Comment: Why don't you simply use the `env` scope? (`$env:PATH`)

Comment: @Mathias, no, this doesn't work, you can see my attachment picture.

Comment: @ Ansgar, the env issue is that it could not reload the environment from the regedit, what I used this PS script is to set the PATH value, but $env:PATH could not be loaded unless I restarted.

Comment: Ansgar, once the env get the PATH value, it could not reload the newest PATH value from the regedit, I want it to get the newest PATH value from regedit without restart the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a script to just echo the current value of a given user environment variable simply expanding the respective value should work just fine:

```psh
Get-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\Environment -Name $args[0] -EA SilentlyContinue |
  select -Expand $args[0]
```

That will echo either the value of the given environment variable, nothing if the variable doesn't exist, or a list of all properties of `HKCU:\Environment` when no argument was passed to the script.

Demonstration:

```
C:\>echo %COMSPEC%
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe

C:\>powershell .\getenv.ps1 foo

C:\>powershell .\getenv.ps1 PATH
C:\bin;C:\apps\ant\bin;C:\Python33\bin

C:\>powershell .\getenv.ps1

DIRCMD       : /o:gn
PATH         : C:\bin;C:\apps\ant\bin;C:\Python33\bin
TEMP         : C:\Users\foo\AppData\Local\Temp
TMP          : C:\Users\foo\AppData\Local\Temp
PSPath       : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment
PSParentPath : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER
PSChildName  : Environment
PSDrive      : HKCU
PSProvider   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry
```

If you want to suppress the property list when no arguments were passed to the script, add a check like this:

```psh
if ($args[0]) {
  Get-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\Environment -Name $args[0] -EA SilentlyContinue |
    select -Expand $args[0]
}
```

Comment: Ansgar Wiechers, Thanks very much, but it still doesn't output anything on my PC. I have updated the captured picture in my POST question. I doubt it might not be script itself issues, but some other setting.  The script is running on Win8.

Comment: @python I cannot reproduce your problem. The code I posted works just fine on the Windows 8.1 I installed for testing this. Try running just `Get-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\Environment -Name $args[0]` without anything else from your script and see if you get an error.

Comment: Ansgar, I still could not get it work. thanks anyway, I will spend sometime to check what caused this issue.